# Help with my basic partitions

Tags: partitioning, restore

download ubuntu, and my partitions became basic to dynamic?

my operating system windows 7: died, and I was trying to fix this problem, I have working files need corel draw, and I have much experience in this, as I can see my partitions "unreadable"?
As I can restore without losing my data

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of Gparted?  Go to the dash and type "gparted", and select "GParted Partition Editor".  Then enter your password and wait for the program to finish loading.  Select your harddrive from the dropdown menu in the upper right corner (if in doubt, choose /dev/sda or /dev/hda).  Finally, press Alt+PrintScreen and save the file somewhere, upload it to an image sharing site like imgur.com, and link to it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the hard drive and hook it up to a running PC. Set up this HD as as slave drive if possible. You can also access this drive via USB. If you have not destroyed or corrupted this drive you will be able to read all your data files and move them to a safer drive. Reformat the drive, reinstall Windows 7 and move your recovered data back to the fresh system. 
Good Luck.